# How to persist data with no direct relation ship in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

I am having a doubt on how to persist data of class which are not directly related.For example take emp class and dept class.This two classes are having relation with other in another class say emp_dept.This class is having primary key of both emp and dept as Primary foreign key..The relation is like one emp  has many emp_dept ,one dept has many emp_dept..please help me with this.Just i am beginner to development.

Comment: This is not a `no direct relationship` but is a perfectly valid `ManyToMany` relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the @OneToMany annotation with the @JoinTable annotation. For your example, it will look like as follows;

```
  @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)  
  @JoinTable(name = "EMP_DEPT", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "dept_id") })  
  private List<Department> departmentList = new ArrayList<Department>(0);
```

Here the departmentList is the list of Department objects that one employee can be in. I am assuming that is the relationship you are trying to build here. The join column will have the primary key of the main table which is the Employee and the invert join column will have the primary key of the Department entity.

Hope this helps.